will string literals be contiguous in memory in C
I came across this, where dereferencing a-3 memory address gives me the char present in b.
char *b = "welcome";
{
    char *a = "home";
    printf("%c", *(a-3));
}

I couldn't find any relative standard to support this.
I tried to compile this with an online C compiler. It returned a char stored in b.
I wanted to understand how this execution is possible.

Unrelated: *(a-3) is more clearly written a[-3]

It is undefined behavior because you asked for a[-3] which is by chance some character in b

You can't understand what is allowed or not in C by doing experiments, you have to read the standard (or a good book).

halfblood_prince, Even if in contiguous memory there were string literals "bbbbb" just before "home" and  "bbbbb" just after that same  "home", printf("%c", *(a-3)); would still not certainly produce "b" as accessing via *(a-3) is undefined behavior.


couldn't find any relative standard to support this

That's because there is none. The program has undefined behavior since you access "home" out of bounds, which means that the program could do just about anything, including what it did in your case.
Never rely on undefined behavior.


Wanted to understand how this execution is possible

The program has undefined behavior because accessing memory outside the array pointed to by the pointer a is invalid: the behavior is undefined, execution may be possible without visible side effects or fail with an explicit error message, the program can print a character consistent with your supposition or some thing different or be terminated abruptly, or go into an infinite loop or anything else... including different behavior for different runs. Nothing can be expected from undefined behavior.
The Standard does not give many guarantees about string literal addresses in memory: they must be different for different string contents, but the relative order is undefined, as a matter of fact, the relative order may not make sense at all because pointers to different arrays can only be compared for equality, not relative order with <, <=, > or >=.
Different instances of the same string literals could have the same address or different addresses, no guarantee about that either.
String literals could even overlap: "hello world" and "world" could be placed in memory such that "hello world" + 6 == "world".  Early C compilers used to take advantage of this to reduce memory footprint. Modern compilers and linkers can still do this, or not, no guarantee.
Your program has undefined behavior, but there is a portable way to test these conditions using printf:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *a = "home";
    const char *b = "welcome";
    const char *c = "come";
    const char *d = "home";

    printf("%p: %s\n", (void *)a, a);
    printf("%p: %s\n", (void *)b, b);
    printf("%p: %s\n", (void *)c, c);
    printf("%p: %s\n", (void *)d, d);
    return 0;
}

The output will show:

For architectures with a linear address space, the relative order in memory of the string constants
whether the strings pointed to by a and d are the same in memory or different.
whether the string "come" is the suffix of the string "welcome" or a separate string constant.

Try this program multiple times, using the same or different compilers, on the same or different targets... The output might differ even for the same executable run again on the same machine.  No guarantees.

The program has undefined behavior since you're trying to access an area outside of "home" by dereferencing memory addresses.
However, to answer your question as to how the execution is possible, the compiler could be storing the string of chars h o m e \0 immediately after the string of chars w e l c o m e \0 in memory.
Since the address a pointer points to is the first character of a string, a would be pointing at the h in memory. If you subtracted 3 from the address a points to, you'd go back 3 bytes in memory, passing the null character at the end of "welcome", passing e, and landing on the m in welcome as the character to print.
Still, as another answer mentioned, this is undefined behavior and should never be relied on since you're accessing a outside the bounds of the string.


I wanted to understand how this execution is possible.

There are at least three ways to think about this:

As several other answers have explained, the behavior here is undefined, which means that just about anything can happen.  The program could print "welcome".  Or, theoretically, it could print "hello", or "goodbye", or "djwjnsdvjnvjsd", or nothing, or anything.
Yes, compilers do tend to store strings in more or less the same part of memory.  So it's not surprising if one string ends up "next to" another in this way.
You would obviously never want to depend on this sort of thing in a "real" program.  It might seem to work, today, but it doesn't work for the right reasons, so it might stop working tomorrow.

The other question is, where did you "come across" this code, and what lesson was its author trying to teach?  Hopefully, the code was not presented as an example of good code, that you would want to emulate in your own work.  Presumably, it was presented as a curiosity, that the author thought you might learn something from.  (And then, whether the lesson you might learn is a valuable one is another story.)

It was just a community post from Elearning youtube channel, i guess it was posted to stir up the curiosity.

Nope, they don´t have to be.  Also, a compiler is permitted to overlap string literals if one of them is a suffix of the other, so you cannot assume they will have some relative position.  BTW the compiler is not enforced to put string literals contiguously, some alginment can be enforced (introducing gaps), they can be positioned in reverse order of source position (so they not have to appear immediately one after the other or in the order they appear in the source), or they can be positioned depending on other factors (e.g. the compiler can allow you to modify string literals, triggering not to overlap them in memory based on use seen in the generated code, this is only an idea, not saying this is used by any compiler)
In addition, the string literals coming from a compilation unit can be located in different sections on the final executable, so the memory positions depend completely on how the linker processes them.

Wanted to understand how this execution is possible

The execution of your code is not possible because the code is not compilable.  But anyway, the expression you use (*(a-3))  is actually equivalent to a[-3] or even (-3)[a]  ---being this last a legacy construct that only states the conmutativity of addition but dates from the age of the first compilers, so please, don't use *(a-3) when you want to say a[-3]) is pointing three places out of the string literal array.  If you correct the code to be compilable, the execution is still possible because in C no array bounds checking is done (for efficiency reasons) and this is what triggers the Undefined Behaviour.  Undefined behaviour means executable code can be produced, but the execution results is not predictable at all.
As the code is not correct syntax, I assume (probably erroneously) that both string literals are in the same compilation unit.  As such, the compiler can only overlapp the two string literals if one of them happens to be a suffix of the other (which they are not) so those string literals will never be overlapped.
